# swap "two" column values in two different rows using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two rows each of which contain a week a day and an event. An auto increment primary key is used to distinguish the rows.

Here is an example:

```
ID   Week  Day        event
-------------------------------
1  |  1  |  2  |  house keeping
2  |  2  |  3  |  house viewing
```

What i want to do is swap the week and day of the two rows specified so that it looks like this:

```
ID   Week  Day        event
-------------------------------
1  |  2  |  3  |  house keeping
2  |  1  |  2  |  house viewing
```

But the Id **must** remain the same

Ive been reading through other peoples posts and found this solution which uses temporary variables to swap only one columns values from each row.

```
UPDATE my_table SET a=@tmp:=a, a=b, b=@tmp;
```

Could anyone help me swap two columns instead of just the one?

thanks

Comment: You only need to swap one column, the ID. And frankly, I can't imagine why the scenario you describe would be necessary.

Comment: @JohnFx Lets say there was another column such as an event column associated with each ID where i wanted to swap the dates for the specific event while retaining the ID for the event?

Comment: So why are you hung up on "Swapping" them. Why not just update the date on both events as separate update statements. Or for that matter, wrap it in a transaction if they must happen at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean wrap it in a transaction? i would prefer it in a single query as opposed to multiple queries

Comment: Why only a single query. What is the benefit of that?

Comment: Because using PDO in PHP the query would have to execute twice whereas the example i provided shows that i can be done in one query using temp variables. The question i posed was how could you do the same thing except two columns values instead of one

Comment: Answered updated. Single query. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have just 2 rows in your table.
If not, you need to modify slightly the `JOIN` conditions.

Here is one possible approach.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T(ID int, Week int, Day int)
INSERT INTO T(ID, Week, Day)
SELECT ID, Week, Day from TableName;

UPDATE TableName t1
JOIN T t2 on t1.ID <> t2.ID
SET
t1.Week = t2.Week,
t1.Day = t2.Day;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE T;
```

And here is a better one.

```
UPDATE
    tablename AS t1
    JOIN tablename AS t2 ON
           ( t1.id <> t2.id )
SET
    t1.week = t2.week,
    t2.week = t1.week,
    t1.day = t2.day,
    t2.day = t1.day;
```

Comment: The answer i was looking for thank you Peter. I thought i might have to create a temporary table but wondered if it could be done with temp variables instead

Comment: @KyleT Actually, seems it can be done without variables at all.

Comment: Yes i have just seen your revised post. A very clean way of doing it too

Comment: Um <> ? That is basically a cross join, also there is no need for a temporary table;  Also confused on how updating the same table twice and saying t1.week = t2.week   but right after set t2.week back to t1.week but both t1 and t2 reference same table

Comment: @mhoglan I assume OP has just 2 rows in his table so I join with <>. "Also confused on how updating the same table twice" Just try it and Google it, this is OK. This is because the different assignments ( = ) apparently are not executed sequentially (internally MySQL probably has the temporary variables anyway). SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9afa0d/1

Comment: I read it different... was thinking swapping column values, not row.  sorry :)

Comment: @mhoglan Thats what i told you in your post but thanks for the answer. I tried Peters code and it resolves the problem perfectly